# C# .NET Core IoT Error for ARM embedded board : Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Device or resource busy

Tags: c#, .net-core, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I want to use **.NET core IoT library** in order to run **C#** code for my **SAMA5D27 SOM1 EK1 ARM embedded board**.

[.NET core IoT github](https://github.com/dotnet/iot)

I have build this .NET core project composed from **project.cs** source file :

```
using System;
using System.Device.Gpio;
using System.Threading;

namespace led_blink
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pin = 81;
            var lightTimeInMilliseconds = 1000;
            var dimTimeInMilliseconds = 200;
            
            Console.WriteLine($"Let's blink an LED!");
            using (GpioController controller = new GpioController())
            {
                controller.OpenPin(pin, PinMode.Output);
                Console.WriteLine($"GPIO pin enabled for use: {pin}");

                Console.CancelKeyPress += (object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs eventArgs) =>
                {
                    controller.Dispose();
                };

                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Light for {lightTimeInMilliseconds}ms");
                    controller.Write(pin, PinValue.High);
                    Thread.Sleep(lightTimeInMilliseconds);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Dim for {dimTimeInMilliseconds}ms");
                    controller.Write(pin, PinValue.Low);
                    Thread.Sleep(dimTimeInMilliseconds);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is **.csproj** file :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Iot.Device.Bindings" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Device.Gpio" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

As you can see, the code is used for blinking Led which is situated on **PIN 81** which corresponds to **PortC pin 17** on my board. I build the project in order to use on **arm-linux** board.

First, to check if the pin is working well, I used libgpiod library and I turned on the led of pin81 using `gpioset gpiochip0 81=1` and it is working well.

Furthermore, I have checked my GPIOs using `gpioinfo` command and this is the result of the desired pin :

```
 line  81:       "PC17"       unused   input  active-high
```

But when I try to run the C# code, it fails with this output message :

```
Let's blink an LED!
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Device or resource busy
   at System.IO.FileStream.WriteNative(ReadOnlySpan`1 source)
   at System.IO.FileStream.FlushWriteBuffer()
   at System.IO.FileStream.FlushInternalBuffer()
   at System.IO.FileStream.Flush(Boolean flushToDisk)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Flush()
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose()
   at System.IO.File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents)
   at System.Device.Gpio.Drivers.SysFsDriver.OpenPin(Int32 pinNumber)
   at System.Device.Gpio.GpioController.OpenPin(Int32 pinNumber)
   at System.Device.Gpio.GpioController.OpenPin(Int32 pinNumber, PinMode mode)
   at led_blink.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/ubuntu/netcore/Program.cs:line 23
Aborted
```

This is my board device tree :

[device_tree](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/boot/dts/at91-sama5d27_som1_ek.dts)

PS : I have removed ISC node which is using PC17 GPIO from device tree in order to free the pin

[ISC_DeviceTree_node](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/boot/dts/at91-sama5d27_som1_ek.dts#L70)

Why my code can't run ? any help please !

Comment: What hardware is doing the USB to Serial Conversion?  What driver are you using?  Common error is the Microsoft Standard USB to RS-232 driver was installed instead of the correct vendor driver.  Each vendor USB to RS-232 is different.

Comment: Try this app note : http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/AN_3326-How-to-use-SAMA5D2-USB-Mass-Storage-Gadget-Under-Linux-00003326a.pdf  There are a lot more app notes at following : https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATSAMA5D27-SOM1#datasheet-toggle

Comment: @jdweng well If this helps, i have build the Linux 4.14.73 image using yocto project and I used the SAMA5D27 configuration for the build. I don't think that it's a wrong driver

Comment: @jdweng besides, I am using only J10 serial USB for my work. And not J17 USBA that is described in the note you mentioned

Comment: Look at following page.  It has been updated recently.  Read the DTS page.  There is a line numbered 54 near top with an example.  One guess is the boot is not configuring every thing properly.

Comment: Are you sure your IoT C# support in Mono has this PR included https://github.com/dotnet/iot/pull/219? Also, are you sure it supports your kernel / libgpiod version?

Comment: Okay, seems I have a lead here. You are using defaults, which are logical pin numbering schema + sysfs driver. Your kernel perhaps does not enable sysfs interface. But I recommend to use libgpiod driver.

Comment: How does this have anything to do with File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents) which is causing the exception?

Comment: @0andriy I am using **4.14** linux kernel version and I have included Libgpiod **1.0.1** library. Sorry but I did not get the problem which I must fix

Comment: I know what the issue is, not sure how to fix (See https://tewarid.github.io/2014/01/07/driving-an-led-with-a-raspberry-pi.html).  The I/O must be links to a device in /sys/class/gpio/.  Instead it is connected to a filestream (probably the smart card).

Comment: Can you run Pinout?  See : https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/

Comment: @jdweng I think that I .NET core IoT must use LIBGPIOD driver for my board instead of SYSFS driver. Do you have an idea how to modify my code to do this ? I am not expert with C#

Comment: If you are using LIBGPIOD than see tools under following to get similar info : https://github.com/brgl/libgpiod  and https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod/+/v0.2.x/README.md

Comment: The following page shows the condfiguration for chip bcm2835 : https://www.beyondlogic.org/an-introduction-to-chardev-gpio-and-libgpiod-on-the-raspberry-pi/  If you use command gpiodetect you will get an output showing the device being used and the configuration of the pins to verify you are set up correctly.

Comment: @jdweng This is the output of `gpiodetect` :  https://pastebin.com/HLy3rj4H  and this is for `gpioinfo` : https://pastebin.com/99nnTGJp

Comment: I'm blocked from seeing the pastebin pictures until later today.  Are the pins you are using set correct and is the device part number correct?

Comment: @jdweng yes everything is correct

Comment: So pin 81 is the correct number for the light?  I don't have source so we need to find out why writing to pin 81 is executing the instruction WriteAllText().  The WriteAllText is causing an exception due to the file not being mounted.  So either we mount the drive or figure out why the WriteAllText() is executing.

Comment: I was just thinking about recent changes (this week) to the Raspberry event handlers.  I didn't think it was related to your issue.  But if there your code is triggering an event then that could account for the WriteAllText().

Comment: I think I found one error.   It is not Pin 81. Should be PB1.   Look at para 3.2 (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/AN_3293-How-to-Use-SAMA5D2-GPIO-Under-Linux-00003293a.pdf)  Each PB number is two pins.  So PB1 = Pin 34.  Also check Events in Para 4.4 number 7 : Monitor the PB2 pin status.  You want PB2 instead of PB1.  Try with event off on PB2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly i found the solution. You must use LibGpioD driver instead of SysFs interface in your Linux platform and your C# code.

Answer (score 0):

OK.   Been working with embedded systems for 45 years.  Initially I thought the error was coming from a PC connected to the board.  I realize now that the device is console serial port.

The device is booting off eprom and first configures console so for debugging.  Next the device is trying to mount the operating system from disk.  You device has a smart card that is on a USB connection.  I was reading your source code and thought the USB was the RS-232 but from device literature the USB is used for the smart card.  The error looks like it may be from the startup code for the smart card.  So either the card is not inserted, not formatted, or no operating system on card.

You may not need to smart card depending on your requirements.  I'm using at work a Xilinx Embedded card and not using smart card so we have to boot option turned off to work with smart  card.  We also had to program the Xilinx before using.  I assume Atmel has similar options.

Comment: sorry but I did not understand your answer

Comment: Sorry.  I believe there is something not being configured in the startup.  I'm not sure why writing to the LED is causing an issue with the FILESTREAM. The real issue is the WriteAllText().  So it looks like you cannot write the text to a file.  The file is on the smart card.  So something in the startup is not mounting the smart card.

Comment: What you are talking about? It has little to do with the Q.

Comment: Look at the error messages.  The device has lots of options with the switches, compiler options, and configuration file.   You have OpenPin(Int32 pinNumber, PinMode mode) and the PinMode is (or compiler option) is setting an option to write all messages to a file (File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents).  The exception is due to device not being able to write the text to a file.

Comment: Have you any experience with Linux kernel ABIs, in particular sysfs?

Comment: I worked with unix for over 25 years (not recently) and debugged similar issues.  The code should not be calling WriteAllText() and that is the issue the need to be investigated.  The OP does not need this feature.  There are two way of fixing issue. 1) Eliminate the WriteAllText() 2) Mount the smart card so the write will work.

Comment: What is bothering me right now is the exception looks like a Net Library stack trace with the messages being in reverse order and not a linux error.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many years your are working in the area, the question is about Linux specific interfaces and thus if you don't know about sysfs and GPIO sysfs legacy interface along with how kernel communicates with user space, nothing can be add here. For your convenience: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/gpio/sysfs.html

Comment: I know unix very well and linux interfaces and boot process is very similar to unix.  I've already found the issue and reported the issue above.

Comment: I guess from the link the following was occurring which was writing to disk because an unused I/O pin was being used:  If you use poll(2), set the events POLLPRI and POLLERR. If you use select(2), set the file descriptor in exceptfds. After poll(2) returns, either lseek(2) to the beginning of the sysfs file and read the new value or close the file and re-open it to read the value.  Did you figure this out?